# Save Current Recorded Macro in Notepad++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

[image: Installed Plugins]

I'm hoping someone can help, or at least identify this is a known issue.

I'm able to record a macro in Notepad++ (Windows 7, 64-bit) and "stop recording" but at any time after that, the Macro menu choice `Save Current Recorded Macro` is greyed out.

I've tried doing this while running Notepad++ both as my standard user and as an Administrator, both times unable to Save Current Recorded Macro.

Since I'm not sure if an installed plugin is causing a conflict, I'm attaching a screenshot.

Thanks in advance for any help, Adam

Comment: Have you have tried an earlier build?  Have you been able to at any point record a macro and save it?

Comment: Hi, I have to get the version number. This is the first time recording macros in several years so it would have been many versions and computers ago. Would prefer to use up to date version anyway

Comment: My version is 6.7.7

Comment: Report the problem and use several previous versions to see if it works in those versions